# How would one setup a website like MSDN Powershell documentation?

Tags: website-design, github, git, jekyll

Not fully sure if this is the place to ask, but here goes nothing:

The [MSDN PowerShell documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/powershell-scripting) uses a git repository for its source.

I would like to setup something similar. I tried with github pages, but all I managed where some separate pages ([like this](https://invoke-automation.github.io/AtlassianCLI/Add-JIRAIssue)) without any global menu, navigation, footer or logo.

I don't know what technologies or configurations are used to setup the MSDN site and that's what I'm looking for. I looked into jekyll but I'm not sure if that is something that could solve my problem. (If you think that is what I should be using pleas say so)

The feature I would love (and have no clue how to start setting it up):

- Menus, navigation, breadcrumbs that are "around" the page to enable users to navigate to other documentation pages.

Any tips or finger pointing in the right direction (demo's or blog posts) would be welcome. I am a system engineer not a web developer so be gentle on the jargon.